# Can't make EF Code First work with manually changed data base

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've added two new properties to my domain model class and two properties to a data table accordingly. Then I tried to launch my mvc web application and got

```
The model backing the 'EFDbContext' context has changed since the database was created.  
Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database  
(http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

Having read the following posts:

[MVC3 and Code First Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254613/mvc3-and-code-first-migrations)

[EF 4.3 Automatic Migrations Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx)

I tried to `Update-Database` through *Package Manager Console*, but got an error

```
Get-Package : Не удается найти параметр, соответствующий имени параметра "ProjectName".
C:\Work\MVC\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:611 знак:40
+     $package = Get-Package -ProjectName <<<<  $project.FullName | ?{ $_.Id -eq 'EntityFramework' }
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Package], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.GetPackageCommand

The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'Domain'.
```

But the *Entityframework* is installed on project *Domain*. I removed it from references, deleted *package.config* and sucessfully reinstalled EF. But `Update-Database` still returns same error. `Update-Database -Config` does as well

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Many thanks to Ladislav Mrnka, I'll try to rephrase my question. As far as I changed my data table manually, I am not expected to use migration. But how can I now make EF work with manually edited domain model class and data table?

Comment: Do you want to use migrations or do you simply want EF to work with your manually changed database? The point of migrations is to let EF define and update your database.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I "*simply want EF to work with your manually changed database*"...as I am new to EF, I came to a thought that migration is the cue for my problem....if I am wrong, direct me the right way, please!

Comment: There are multiple approaches to use EF. You can use code first mapping and maintain database manually or you can use code first and let EF maintain the database - that is what migrations do.

Comment: I did everything manually, but how can I make EF work now?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to add this to startup of your application (you can put it to `App_Start`):

```
Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(null);
```

It should turn off all logic related to handling the database from EF. You will now be fully responsible for keeping your database in sync with your model.

Comment: Now it says *Invalid column name* for both new columns

Comment: Same error is shown by intellisense in SSMS in *Select TOP 1000 rows* command...though it works and returns rows

Comment: So did you add those column to database or not?

Comment: Of course, I did! I added them with the help of SSMS...then wanted just to check it, and opened *Select TOP 1000 rows*..it returned rows..but in the query editor in the select statement intellisense underlined names of the added columns with red line, saying *Invalid column name*

Comment: I tried to replace them with another columns (with different names), but SSMS intellisense still says *Invalid column name...*

Comment: That is a bug in SSMS. It will stop underline them once you refresh the database or restart SSMS. Are those exceptions fired by your application describing columns with correct names?

Comment: Yes, when I start my mvc application I get same messages *Invalid column name...* from mvc in browser when it tries to visualize those entities ina view

Comment: I restarted SSMS, recreated those columns...no red line in SSMS now....but still an error in mvc

Comment: You are either modifying incorrect database or you are not giving those columns correct name (the name from the exception) - I have just tried it myself and it works without any issues.

Comment: That's it...the problem was in my Web.config...forgot to change it when moved my repository to Domain project...`Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(null);` is just what I need...Thank's a lot!!!

Comment: I don't know how it worked at all having a reference to an unexisting repository...but after I added the code that you suggested, the issue was my Web.config

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed the issue.

I dropped table __MigrationHistory using sql command and run the update-database -verbose again.

Apparently something was wrong with this automatic created table.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 2 was exactly what was needed. Although when I got to the App_Start I realized that there were 4 configuration files and didn't see where this would fit in any of them. Instead I added it to my EF database context

```
namespace JobTrack.Concrete
{
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext 
    {
        //Set the entity framework database context to the connection name
        //in the Webconfig file for our SQL Server data source QSJTDB1
        public EFDbContext() : base("name=EFDbConnection")
        {            
        }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Remove the tight dependency on the entity framework that 
        //wants to take control of the database. EF by nature wants
        //to drive the database so that the database changes conform
        //to the model changes in the application. This will remove the
        //control from the EF and leave the changes to the database admin
        //side so that it continues to be in sync with the model.
        Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(null);

        //Remove the default pluaralization of model names
        //This will allow us to work with database table names that are singular
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();            
    }

    //Allows for multiple entries of the class State to be used with 
    //interface objects such as IQueryTables for the State database table  
    public DbSet<State> State { get; set; } 

}
```

}