# Entity Framework and update data

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2014

I have a database. It works fine. But when I try to update data (only data, nothing more, schema stays the same) from another database (more new version of data for database) I get this error:

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

As I understand, this error happens with Entity Framework. I check database schema, It stays the same after updating.

Why do I get this error? Is it a bug with Entity Framework?

Comment: This has already been discussed in another thread.
See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15397640/4806735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was because update data script delete a record from __MigrationHistory table.