# Seeding data for a particular environment in Entity Framework Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using the new way of seeding data in EF Core 2.1 and I want to seed data for the development environment only.

Initially I tried this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") != EnvironmentName.Development)
    {
        return;
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasData(new Customer { ... });
}
```

However, I noticed that the generated migration will always insert the customers into the database.

Is there a way of restricting the data seed on a per environment basis?

Comment: Is this seeding data or creating tables?

Comment: @viveknuna this is seeding data. Tables should be created for all environments. Seed data should only be added for development environment.

Comment: @ChaoticNadirs did you find any good solution yet?

Comment: Your solution works if you set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881069/ef-core-doesnt-use-aspnetcore-environment-during-update-database) other SO article

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit old, but what I did was create extension methods to call from `Startup.cs` and based on if the database exists, seed it or not. I also wrapped that call in an env
The seeding of the db won't happen if the database already exists, however, I believe this behavior is fine, because of the database already exists you are most likely not in a dev environment.

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void UseDbSeeding(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var factory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        using var serviceScope = factory.CreateScope();
        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        if(context.Database.EnsureCreated()) // false when db already exists
        {
            // Seed here
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And from `Startup.cs`

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) 
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDbSeeding();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do in Startup.cs in `ConfigureServices` method like this

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
   // then seed data
```

Here is recommended way to seed data in Asp.Net Core (Note that I'm not checking environment here). Please look at my sample [here](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/Program.cs#L12-L17)

And [this](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Entities/Data/SeedData.cs) file will be use to at run time seed

Comment: `DbContext` contructor should be changed iand inject `IHostingEnvironment`