# How do I update my prod database with dotnet ef database cli command?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1, dotnet-cli, dotnetcorecli

How do I get EF to build all the tables for the prod db?

So far I've been building and pushing all my .Net Core database migrations to the dev db

ex.

> >dotnet ef migrations add InitialModsN -c Auto2Context
>
> >dotnet ef database update -c Auto2Context

In my Appsettings.Development.json file I have my con string pointing to dev db 'source=DEV'

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=Auto2.db",
"Auto2": "data source=DEV; initial catalog=Auto2; user id=auto2; password=12345;" }
```

And my Appsettings.json I have the prod db con string pointing to the prod db 'source=LIVE'

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=Auto2.db",
"Auto2": "data source=LIVE; initial catalog=Auto2; user id=auto2; password=12345;" }
```

So far everything is being built and migrated to dev, how do I change this to build all the changes up to date in the prod db?

Do I have to re create an initial migration file and then update?
If yes, how do I point it to the prod db?
I tried a couple of different commands with no luck.
Here is what I tried.

> >dotnet ef database update -c Auto2Context --connection "data source=LIVE; initial catalog=Auto2; user id=auto2; password=12345"

-received 'Unrecognized option '--connection''

> >dotnet ef database update -c Auto2Context --configuration Release

- no tables created in the prod db

Answer (score 1):

Set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable before executing the command:

`$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production'`

Comment: Unrecognized option '--environment' and Unrecognized option '-e'

Comment: also I see this: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production' in a couple of different files. Launchsettings.json and launch.json.

Comment: As far as I know `$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production'`should works [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452555/1385614)

Comment: this doesn't seem correct as I would have to go into the file where this line exists and manually change it every time I go in-between dev and prod. That doesn't correct..

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used and it seems to work.

> dotnet publish --configuration Release /p:EnvironmentName=Production

but this only builds the application.
I had to run this command below to create a sql script to update the prod db.

> dotnet ef migrations script -i -o "buildscript.sql" -c Auto2Context

Is this the best/correct way to push db changes to prod?