# Migrations no longer recognized as complete after assembly name change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an project using EF Code First and migrations.  I recently changed the assembly and project names and the namespaces to a new name and continued working on it.

I tried to add a new migration and now it is complaining that I need to complete all the previous migrations before doing so ("Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending").  I looked at the records and they have a ContextKey that has the old assembly name but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Is there a way to make it recognize that the old migrations in the migration history are the same ones that are currently in the assembly?

Comment: Do you really need to keep trace of your old migrations ? If no, you can restart from 0, removing all in your migration code / migration history tables, and re-Enable migrations...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes, because the old version of this application is in production (otherwise I wouldn't have migrations on in the first place).  I guess I could try and work around that although it sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: Does this help ? [Fixing CF Migrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254613/mvc3-and-code-first-migrations/10255051#10255051) - the (3) should work in the worst case. I'm not anywhere near VS, but it can be worked around I'm sure, changing records didn't do anything?