# Empty migration and snapshot conflict in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Say I have an app with this Entity Framework model:

```
public class Author
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Author> Authors{ get; set; }
}
```

So I do the usual stuff where I run the app, and the initial db schema is created, then enable migrations and update the database.

Now, say I add another property to `Author`, `string Bio`. I type `Add-Migration AddBio` and the appropriate files are generated.

Here's where things getconfusing: I've tried comment everything inside the `Up` method of the newly created migration (which is just 1 line for adding a new column, Bio) and do `Update-Database`. Now, when I try to add a new author to my database, I get "error occurred, see inner exception for details" message from the runtime.

I realize that this is as a consequence of inconsistencies between the last model snapshot and the database schema (correct me if I'm wrong). The moment I do `Add-Migration ...` a new model snapshot is created, and it assumes that `Description` is part of the database schema...it's just that it's not.

Is there a way to fix things if I arrive at this sort of situation (I assume this is a very easy way to deliberately confuse someone who's working on a .NET project)? Roll back to the previous migration and then uncomment the code of the latest migration and run it again? Add a (new) migration that will contain the commented out content? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly - you can't really do things like that 'ad hoc', as that's not going to end well. Unless it's all about experimenting - or you really understand all the intricacies involved.

Basically you have '3 parts' involved in the equation:

- your code, POCO classes
- the Db structure, tables etc. that are generated based on your model
- and the `__MigrationHistory` table that holds the 'metadata' and synchronizes the two sort of

what you did is to comment the part that generates necessary fields in the Db - **but your model/classes are still the same** (so you should comment things in there as well, not that I recommend doing it).

```
Bottom line, things need to be and stay in sync.
```

The best way to do that is to avoid any manual changes, either in the Db or in the generated code - and follow best practices rules, i.e. follow what's recommended.

Here are some links (of my answers) describing some more ways to `get into trouble` and get yourself out of it if / when it happens:
[how to manually sync with the Db](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10255051/417747)
[How to delete and recreate from scratch an existing EF Code first database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035333/how-to-delete-and-recreate-from-scratch-an-existing-ef-code-first-database/16082497#16082497)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rollback your latest migration you can try to complete these steps

1) Firstly execute `Get-Migrations` command in 'Package Manager Console' you will receive migrations that have been applied to your database.
for example:
`201605181535083_ThisOneWhichYouWantRollback
 201605181535083_LastSuccessful
 201605181535083_Initial`

2) Execute `update-database -TargetMigration "LastSuccessful"` command. This command will rewind and undo any migrations between the current and the “LastSuccessful” migration.

3) After that you can try to uncomment your migration code and `Update-Database` one more time.

References:
[How to Rollback Entity Framework Code First Migration](http://www.discussiongenerator.com/2015/08/04/how-to-rollback-entity-framework-code-first-migration/)

Comment: Ideally your answer would contain the bulk of the relevant details; link-only answers are considered low quality, as the link can change/go stale/dead over time.  This leaves future readers without an effective answer.